# No module named 'tensorflow.python._impl

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to run code for try neural network with python but 
**No module named 'tensorflow.python._impl**

part of my code:

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python._impl import activations

I did all solutions that some sites said such as
 - Uninstall and install package like tensorflow,..
also:
 - Upgrade tensorflow
 - Upgrade keras

but it doesn't solve yet. I have this error on co lab too.
please help me if you have any solution

thanks

Comment: try changing your last import to `from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import activations`

Comment: Hi Zahra, it would be great if you could edit your post to format your code (by pressing `{}` symbol in the editor, and also provide some details about how you installed the packages, and if you're using any specific environment/virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
from keras.layers.recurrent import ...
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Official TensorFlow Support discourages use of tf.python.* as it is private and intended for development purposes only. While it may work in some cases, it will "break unannounced" in many others.

Instead, try importing tensorflow with the .python portion removed, e.g.:

```
from tensorflow._impl import activations
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57863942/whats-the-difference-between-tensorflow-python-keras-and-tensorflow-keras