# What's the difference between tensorflow.python.keras and tensorflow.keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

As the title says, Are they the same api? When I print the layers module in keras, the result are shown as follow:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers
print(layers)
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
print(layers)
```

**result**

```
<module 'tensorflow.python.keras.api._v1.keras.layers' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/api/_v1/keras/layers/__init__.py'>
<module 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/__init__.py'>
```

We can see that two modules come from different source.

And I find the api module from source code, there is only a BUILD file.

Is there a relation between two modules, what is the mechanism of the api generator?

Comment: I think one of them is the implementation of Keras by the Keras team and the other is the implementation of Keras by the Tensorflow team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything under `tf.python.*` is private, intended for development only, rather than for public use.

Importing from `tensorflow.python` or any other modules (including `import tensorflow_core`...) is not supported, and can break unannounced.

So, it is suggested not to use anything with `tf.python.*`.

Comment: So you decide to hide tensorflow.python, tensorflow.core and tensorflow.compiler modules in   2.4.0 . It will make many code not work ......