# ImportError: cannot import name 'tf2' from 'tensorflow.python' (unknown location)

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror

from tensorflow.python import tf2
ImportError: cannot import name 'tf2' from 'tensorflow.python' (unknown location)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify `tf2`, if you want to use TensorFlow 2 you can simply install

```
pip install tensorflow
```

which installs the latest version of tensorflow. Then to use it in python code, you can simply write

```
import tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

True, but also: Official TensorFlow Support discourages use of tf.python.* as it is private and intended for development purposes only. While it may work in some cases, it will "break unannounced" in many others, often leading to "Module Not Found"

Comment: See also this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57863942/whats-the-difference-between-tensorflow-python-keras-and-tensorflow-keras